# SOLR - Different score to different words in a multi word search query

Tags: solr

I am using SOLR with mongoDB in one of my projects for search. I must say, SOLR is very powerful.
Currently, I am looking for a method to set different scores for different keywords if query is multi word.

e.g. If a user searches of black doll house

the weightage of black should be greater than doll and weightage of doll should be greater than house.

black > doll > house

Is it possible to implement this in SOLR. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a separate weight to each term in the standard lucene query syntax (searching in a field named `text`):

```
text:black^10 text:doll^5 text:house
```

This will give `black` ten times as much weight as `house`, and `doll` five times a much weight as `house`, but only half the weight of `black`. You'll have to tweak the weights to get the results you're looking for. If you want to use the regular text in the `q=` field with (e)dismax as the query parser, you can use `bq` to add apply these boosts separately from the query itself.

Comment: I want to use q = "complete text" as search is done in multiple fields through a parser.

Comment: Then you can use `bq` with the `field:foo^boost`-syntax to keep your query identical to what it already is. You can't boost single terms without adding those boosts to the term somewhere :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try boosting the terms in the query. you can specify different boost value for a term in the query. 
example: if you transform your query to :

`textfeild:black^6 textfeild:doll^5 textfeild:house^2`

you get results with top documents will be matched for black, next black, next with house.

it multiplies term weight with boost value. here black with 6, doll with 5 and house with 2.

Comment: I want to use q = "complete text" as search is done in multiple fields through a parser.

Comment: as @MatsLindh mentioned consider `Boost Query(bq)` which specifies a factor by which a term or phrase should be "boosted"